# Handle Android application for multiple clients (multiple servers)

Tags: android, cloud

I'm here to discuss about different ways to handle an Android application that can point its APIs to a server A (ie. httq://a.myproduct.com/api/...) for the client A, or an other server B (ie. httq.://b.myproduct.com/api/...) for another client B.

What i do actually is to generate different APK of the same app for each client. This solution is okay for one or two client, but will become quite heavy to deal with later..

I'm trying to find a better way to have one unique APK which can work with different server url. 
Another constraint is that on a same device, i can have an app that talk to server A and an other app that talk to server B.

Here are the solution I came up with :

- Keep going with multiple APK...
- Have a "central" server that each app calls the first time to know with which server it has to talk and that store that in shared preferences.
- Have a file store somewhere that make the link between an app and a server 
  for example:

  ```
  com.mycompany.productA:httq://a.mycloud.com
  com.mycompany.productB:httq://b.mycloud.com
  ```

But how to handle this file ? What is creating it ?

- Use Android account system ? Create an account for each cloud ? I don't really know..

Does anyone, already experienced this ?

Comment: How do you find out that client opening your Generic version is client A or B? Answer to this question will lead us to possible solutions.

Comment: We are pushing those application on client devices. We know that the device X is owned by our client ClientA. So we install the app which is linked to the cloud http://clientA.mycloud.com

Comment: Right. Given you are using central server method, how are you going to find out that someone connecting to your server is ClientA?

Comment: Using IMEI we can identify the device and so the ClientA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you are able to map connecting devices IMEI to clients, I will briefly give you pros and cons of the three methods you mentioned.

**Multiple APK's**

- Fully isolating client from other knowledge - safe
- Not scalable and maintainable (issuing updates if needed).

**Central Server**

- Scalable, easy to update information (in case you change a.mycloud.com to a2.mycloud.com)
- Not as robust. What if server goes down? Possible attacks, or bugs to worry about.

**All URLs embedded into APK**

- Stable and does not have large overhead in time/resources spent of your team.
- Insecure, you should assume people having access to APK will have access to the file mapping IMEI's to companies.
- If client's IMEI data or company url's is sensitive data, then a big no-no.

Are you a large company? If yes, then you are probably having production servers already and could go with second method.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The first solution is acceptable for the moment, and can maybe be later if we can automate the release process. The last solution seems quite dangerous to store IMEI mapping in APK. For now, it seems to me that the central server can be the best solution. We could even release an demo app (talk to demo.mycloud.com) on a client device.

Comment: Having a server always sounds attractive, but sooner or later many start regretting due to all the troubles from maintenance and overhead costs. P.S. If you are happy with the answer, you could also vote it up ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can build a generic app and use some sort of auth system on the client app. For example, if the user identifies himself as "Client A", your web-service can "tell" your app to use the first endpoint. If it's "Client B", then it will be second endpoint. Bottom line is: make your users sign-in and then use credentials to distinguish the users.

Comment: In fact, these app does not have auth system. It's business application B2B. Not B2C.